# How to read & plot from .shp files using sf package in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I am new to `geospatial` data & trying to plot using `.shp` file but getting an error.

The **geometry type** in this **.shp** file is `LINESTRING` which seems to be different from `MULTIPOLYGON` which I have plotted before using `sf`

**shape file source:** https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/in_country_boundaries.shp

**original source of shapefile:** https://github.com/wri/wri-bounds/blob/master/dist/in_countries.zip

**Expecting result:**

[image]

**code attempt:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

ind_global <- sf::read_sf("path/in_country_boundaries.shp") 
ind_global
```

output

```
Simple feature collection with 412 features and 9 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -141.0056 ymin: -54.88624 xmax: 140.9776 ymax: 70.07531
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

```
ind_global %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

> Error in st_cast.POINT(X[[i]], ...) : cannot create MULTILINESTRING
> from POINT

Do I need to handle `LINESTRING` geometry .shp file in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is running fine after removing `st_as_sf() %>%`. I have downloaded the shapefile from https://github.com/wri/wri-bounds/blob/master/dist/in_countries.zip and it is MULTIPOLYGON only.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

ind_global <- sf::read_sf("...\\in_countries.shp") 
ind_global

ind_global %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

Comment: Thanks @Bappa Das, I don't know why there was an issue with extracted .shp file earlier. After download/extraction again got multipolygon file & it worked as you said. Thanks again for your help. Appreciate it!!